# ImageMagick to preprocess image for tesseract-ocr

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, ocr, tesseract

Is there anyway to process an image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuUFO.png) with ImageMagick so that I can use tesseract-ocr to convert it to text?

Because of the lines in the background I get nonsense from conventional methods. Does anyone know how to deal with an image such as this?

'convert -density 300 -units PixelsPerInch -type Grayscale +compress input.png input.tif' followed by 'tesseract input.tif output -l eng' gives me utter garbage.

Or are there any alternatives to ImageMagick that I can use to pre-process such an image whether through command-line or in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried morphology operations [Morphology of Shapes](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#basic) after converting image to grayscale?

Comment: How to use this ?